# Why am I getting null pointer execepiton while finding a view of a fragment by ID?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, findviewbyid

I am getting error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.dhruv.parqueue/com.example.dhruv.parqueue.UserProfile}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.view.View android.app.Dialog.findViewById(int)' on a null
>   object reference

Here is my code

```
public class UserProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

    FragmentManager fm;
    CheckBox showPassword;
    Dialog passwordChangeDialog;
    private ImageView imageView;
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    private final int SELECT_PHOTO = 1;
    TextView nameText, contactText, emailText;
    PasswordChangeFragment passwordChangeFragment;
    Button confirmButton, changePassword, pickImage;
    EditText nameEdit, contactEdit, newPassword, oldPassword;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);

        preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyFiles", MODE_PRIVATE);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        pickImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_pick);
        changePassword = (Button) findViewById(R.id.changePassword);

        fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        passwordChangeFragment = PasswordChangeFragment.newInstance("Change Password");
        passwordChangeDialog = passwordChangeFragment.getDialog();

        showPassword = (CheckBox) passwordChangeDialog.findViewById(R.id.show_password);
        newPassword = (EditText) passwordChangeDialog.findViewById(R.id.new_password);
        oldPassword = (EditText) passwordChangeDialog.findViewById(R.id.old_password);
        confirmButton = (Button) passwordChangeDialog.findViewById(R.id.confirm_btn);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("editButtonClicked", false);
        editor.commit();

        setProfile();

        pickImage.setVisibility(pickImage.GONE);
        changePassword.setVisibility(changePassword.GONE);

        new ProfileSyncTask().execute();

        pickImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
            }
        });

        changePassword.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                passwordChangeFragment.show(fm, "change_password_fragment");
            }
        });

        showPassword.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (!isChecked) {
                    newPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                } else {
                    newPassword.setInputType(129);
                }
            }
        });

        confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (matchpassword(oldPassword.getText().toString())) {
                    String changedPassword = newPassword.getText().toString();
                    //Write this password to Database and Display Success using AlertFragment
                } else {
                    //Display Wrong Password using AlertFragment
                }
            }
        });

    }
.
.
.
}
```

I am getting the error at line:

```
showPassword = (CheckBox) passwordChangeDialog.findViewById(R.id.show_password);
```

Here is the full error

```
02-03 13:54:49.112 24058-24058/com.example.dhruv.parqueue E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.dhruv.parqueue, PID: 24058
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dhruv.parqueue/com.example.dhruv.parqueue.UserProfile}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.app.Dialog.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.app.Dialog.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.dhruv.parqueue.UserProfile.onCreate(UserProfile.java:97)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here is the code for file change_password_fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="50dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/old_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/current_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/new_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/new_password"
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/show_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/show_password" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/confirm_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/Confirm" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Edit:

I changed my code (as per the suggestion) and implemented onCreateDialog as follows

```
public class PasswordChangeFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public PasswordChangeFragment() {
      }

    public static PasswordChangeFragment newInstance(String title, String userID) {
        PasswordChangeFragment frag = new PasswordChangeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", title);
        args.putString("userID", userID);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.change_password_fragment, container);
    }

    View myView;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        String title = getArguments().getString("title", "Change Password");
        final String userID = getArguments().getString("userID", "");
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage("foo")
                .setPositiveButton("Start timer", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // Cancel
                    }
                });
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.change_password_fragment, null);
        builder.setView(myView);

        final CheckBox showPassword = (CheckBox) myView.findViewById(R.id.show_password);
        final EditText newPassword = (EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.new_password);
        final EditText oldPassword = (EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.old_password);
        final Button confirmButton = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.confirm_btn);

        showPassword.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (!isChecked) {
                    newPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                } else {
                    newPassword.setInputType(129);
                }
            }
        });

        confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Helper helper = new Helper();
                try {
                    if (helper.matchPassword(userID, oldPassword.getText().toString())) {
                        String changedPassword = newPassword.getText().toString();
                        //Write this password to Database and Display Success using AlertFragment
                    } else {
                        //Display Wrong Password using AlertFragment
                    }
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        // Get field from view
        String title = getArguments().getString("title", "Change Password");
        final String userID = getArguments().getString("userID", "");
        // Fetch arguments from bundle and set title
        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        PasswordChangeFragment passwordChangeFragment = PasswordChangeFragment.newInstance(title, userID);
    }
}
```

Now I am getting the error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      Process: com.example.dhruv.parqueue, PID: 3564
      android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:317)
      at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:231)
      at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:423)
      at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:394)
      at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:295)
      at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.onStart(DialogFragment.java:406)
      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1986)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1102)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Instantiate the buttons with new Buttons(); and other components too..they are null because not instantiated..and do some research before posting such questions as you may get too many downvotes

Comment: Where did u infalte the Dialog layout in the code?

Comment: post your xml and the code of PasswordChangeFragment

Comment: My best guess would be that getDialog() returns null becaue you wont create that dialog until PasswordChangeFragment's onCreateView is called, but simply creating a new Fragment wont call onCreateView. But please post the source for PasswordChangeFragment like others said, otherwise its hard to tell.

Comment: `passwordChangeFragment = PasswordChangeFragment.newInstance("Change Password");
asswordChangeDialog = passwordChangeFragment.getDialog();` return null. Check your `PasswordChangeFragment.newInstance()' method

Answer (score 1):

The `PasswordChangeFragment`, live every Fragment, has to go through its lifecycle. You can't make any assumption on  when Android is going to call [onCreatDialog](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#onCreateDialog(android.os.Bundle)) whose result is returned by `getDialog()`. You should get rid of

```
 showPassword = (CheckBox) passwordChangeDialog.findViewById(R.id.show_password);
 newPassword = (EditText) passwordChangeDialog.findViewById(R.id.new_password);
 oldPassword = (EditText) passwordChangeDialog.findViewById(R.id.old_password);
 confirmButton = (Button) passwordChangeDialog.findViewById(R.id.confirm_btn);
```

From your Activity and deal with them in the `DialogFragment`'s subclass. There are a lot of different ways to pass the results back to your Activity if you need them

Comment: Where will I set listeners to these items.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to take a look to the DialogFragment's documentation

Comment: Thanks for the advice @blackbelt

Answer (score 1):

```
passwordChangeFragment = PasswordChangeFragment.newInstance("Change Password");
passwordChangeDialog = passwordChangeFragment.getDialog();
```

Calling `getDialog()` method right after creating your DialogFragment will return null because it isn't created yet. DialogFragment will call `onCreateDialog()` later to get the dialog, so you should override this method and put your `findViewById()` methods there.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
 PasswordChangeFragment passwordChangeFragment  = new PasswordChangeFragment().newInstance("Change Password");
 Dialog passwordChangeDialog = passwordChangeFragment.getDialog();
```